# PhpStorm-Vagrant-VVV Cant connect remote php interpreters

Tags: vagrant, phpstorm, vvvv

Windows7 - VAgrant 1.76 - VirtualBox5 - Phpstorm9
My connection SSH via phpstorm terminal works with vagrant/vagrant user/password.
But I'm not able to connect to the php remote interpreter.
No path mapping were found.[image]
THanks to help me!

When I try to change the remote folder I got this
[image]

Comment: Will it work if you configure it by using "SSH Credentials" .. or by configuring and using SFTP Deployment entry? Try the 2nd one in particular.

Comment: No same error with ssh or SFTP

Comment: Anything interesting in detailed logs? https://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-1202

Comment: in my log a got : WARN - lugins.remotesdk.RemoteSdkUtil -  
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

Comment: You showed just a fraction of the log -- it does not allow me to tell anything from it (except the possible fact that there seems to be a connectivity issue (delay?). Here is another user that seems to have the same issue (based on your log) -- you can post your details/log file there: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-28279

Comment: Complete log : https://www.dropbox.com/s/150wucquzfk4gdv/idea.log?dl=0

Comment: As far as I can tell .. it's the same issue as in the aforementioned ticket. consider communicating with devs there -- ATM I have nothing else to offer that will help you with resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

How I fix it : set **UseDNS No** to /etc/ssh/sshd_config
Modify : sudo nano -w /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in the xdebug.ini file from vagrant config folder  (\config\php5-fpm-config/xdebug.ini)
In the line :

```
xdebug.remote_host = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
```

Have your local machine IP. You can get in windows by enter in cmd->command and type "ipconfig".

Comment: what has this todo with xdebug?

Comment: @Jonathan: If you believe it's not useful or relevant, that's a good reason to downvote it. It should not be flagged as _Not an Answer_, however, since it proposes an answer.

Comment: @JeremyCaney thanks for the feedback, I'll take note of it

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it